# Creating single node module to access multiple extended classes in separate files authored in coffeescript

Tags: node.js, inheritance, module, coffeescript, npm

I'd like to create a single node library that includes multiple classes, each authored using coffee-script in a different file and extending from one another. For instance, say I have the following files in node_modules/mymodule/src:

**File 1:**

```
  class Base
    constructor: (@foo) ->

  module.exports = Base
```

**File 2:**

```
  Base = require './Base.coffee'

  class Derived extends Base
    constructor: (@bar) ->
      super

  module.exports = Derived
```

**File 3:**

```
  Base = require './Base.coffee'

  class Derived2 extends Base
    constructor: (@baz) ->
      super

  module.exports = Derived2
```

Is there some way I can bind these 3 classes in such a way so that I can define "mymodule" in package.json file and then access the module and its classes like so?

**File using mymodule:**

```
  my module = require 'mymodule'

  Base = new mymodule.Base
  Derived = new my module.Derived
  Derived2 = new my module.Derived2
  #Do stuff
```

I don't know what to do in package.json to make this happen, and I can't find documentation on this anywhere. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [main](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html) to configure the entry point you your module and expose your classes there. (I haven't done this with coffee-script).

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports object will be returned.
>
> This should be a module ID relative to the root of your package folder.

Configure your main to point at `index.js` or similar.  Your index.js would then look something like this:

```
module.exports.Base     = require('./pathtobase/Base.coffee');
module.exports.Derived  = require('./pathtobase/Derived.coffee');
module.exports.Derived2 = require('./pathtobase/Derived2.coffee');
```